# Convert Array into array of Hashes

Tags: ruby, arrays

Couldn't find this specific instance anywhere; I might be missing something simple, but here it goes.

Say I have an array:

```
["Field1", "Field2"]
```

I need to convert this into an array of hashes, as such (the FieldType key/value is a default value)

```
[{"Name"=>"Field1", "FieldType"=>"Text"}, 
 {"Name"=>"Field2", "FieldType"=>"Text"}]
```

How would I go about doing this? The below clearly doesnt work:

```
fields.each do |field|
  fieldResults << {"Name" => field, "FieldType" => "Text"}
end
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assuming `fieldResults` is an array, what you wrote should work, though it's more idiomatic to use a better-suited function, like `map`.

```
fields.map {|field| { 'Name' => field, 'FieldType' => 'Text' }}
```

Comment: map worked, for whatever reason I couldn't get my code (above) to work. Thank you!

Comment: took me forever to find this result on google even with the search "convert array into array of hashes". Thank goodness I finally found your answer!

Answer (score 1):

If `fields = ["Field1", "Field2"]` and **fieldResults is initialized to `[]`** your code should work. But as Chuck said `fieldResults = fields.map {|field| { 'Name' => field, 'FieldType' => 'Text' }}` is more ideomatic.

By the way: The ruby naming convention for symbols, methods and *variables* is to use snake_case (underscores) rather than camelCase for multiple word names. Like `field_results` instead of `fieldResults`

Answer (score 0):

You can take the below approach too :

```
fields = ["Field1", "Field2"]
result = fields.map{|i| {"Name" => i}.update({"FieldType" => "Text"})}
# => [{"Name"=>"Field1", "FieldType"=>"Text"},
#     {"Name"=>"Field2", "FieldType"=>"Text"}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing this.

```
fieldResults = []
["Field1", "Field2"].each{|e| fieldResults << Hash["Name",e,"FieldType","Text"]}
1.9.3 (main):0 > fieldResults
 => [{"Name"=>"Field1", "FieldType"=>"Text"},
    {"Name"=>"Field2", "FieldType"=>"Text"}]
```